# Dendrogram d3js with images and labels

Tags: d3.js

how to generate a network/Dendrogram d3 like the linked imaged but with the avatar and labels in vertical mode not with path orientation (translate,rotation)?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfdJs.png

i´m try to using this block as base code http://bl.ocks.org/bansaghi/e490c7c238a67a77996d

Comment: Yes, it is possible!